# Where can I find the top SharePoint apps store lists

Tags: sharepoint-addin

Where can I find the top (e.g. top 10 for 2014, most downloaded ...) SharePoint apps store lists.

to be clear I need some information as:

- Best Android Apps of 2014:
  https://play.google.com/store/apps/collection/promotion_3000f13_best_of_2014?hl=en
- List of most downloaded Android applications: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_most_downloaded_Android_applications

note: I sow the app sore lists, it is not correct, as example highest rated apps is not a highest rated apps.

Answer (score 0):

Uptil Sep 2014, it was possible to query the Sharepoint Store API using REST for number of downloads information but unfortunately that was discontinued.

Anton Khritonenkov has written previously about how he was able to connect and retrieve information here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/796571/Analyze-and-start-using-API-of-SharePoint-App-Stor

However, since the support for retriving downloads has discontinued, he did get a snapshot before the service was made unavailable and can be found here 
http://plumsail.com/blog/2014/10/sharepoint-office-app-store-facts-interesting-statistics/

I am not pasting that information here because that information is quite large. There is also a excel spreadsheet with all the information collated which you can download from there.

Comment: is there anyway to get latest information

Comment: From the Sharepoint Store API, as of the moment, No.

Comment: I am not a liberty to answer anything but "stay tuned" . Apart from the download data which Microsoft does not provide anymore, we are working on an indepent review site which has all the Apps available in the Store. You can use the site to store all your own App reviews in Local Storage (including totally ignoring apps) or become part of the Reviewers community adn share your reviews with the world... site is about to go live for alpha testing this week.

Answer (score -1):

As stated in the other answer the download information is no longer available to the public.

A team of Office365/SharePoint experts is working together on a better user experience for browsing Apps.

The first version is now public at http://OfficeAppCoach.com

Comment: is this is an office site? is it a Microsoft web site?

Comment: No, community innitiative. It  scrapes all public information from the Office Store.